# Update/change a UITableView's Accessory if FileManager shows a document exists

Tags: ios, uitableview

In my iOS app, a `UITableView` shows a list of audio tracks. Next to each, there's an [accessory button](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewcell/1623228-accessorytype) that can be clicked to download a file before listening to it.

My download function includes an if/else, printing that the file has already been downloaded if the user has done so. I'd like for it to show a `.checkmark` accessory in the place of the download button when the view opens if the file has been downloaded -- right now, it does that but only after the accessory is tapped.

To set the first accessory, I use:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)

    cell.textLabel?.text = TableData[indexPath.row]

    cell.accessoryType = .detailDisclosureButton

    return cell
}
```

Then in `accessoryButtonTappedForRowWith`, I check if a file has been downloaded and update to a checkmark if it has:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, accessoryButtonTappedForRowWith indexPath: IndexPath) {
    // doSomethingWithItem(indexPath.row)

    if let audioUrl = URL(string: "https://rss.example.com.mp3") {

        // then lets create your document folder url
        let documentsDirectoryURL =  FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!

        // lets create your destination file url
        let destinationUrl = documentsDirectoryURL.appendingPathComponent(audioUrl.lastPathComponent)
        print(destinationUrl)

        // to check if it exists before downloading it
        if FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: destinationUrl.path) {
            print("The file already exists at path")

            let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)
            cell?.accessoryType = .checkmark

            // if the file doesn't exist
        } else {

            // you can use NSURLSession.sharedSession to download the data asynchronously
            URLSession.shared.downloadTask(with: audioUrl, completionHandler: { (location, response, error) -> Void in
                guard let location = location, error == nil else { return }
                do {
                    // after downloading your file you need to move it to your destination url
                    try FileManager.default.moveItem(at: location, to: destinationUrl)
                    print("File moved to documents folder")
                } catch let error as NSError {
                    print(error.localizedDescription)
                }

            }).resume()

        }
    }
```

My theory is that because the `.checkmark` line happens in a function that requires tapping on the accessory, it can't be changed before the element is clicked, like I want.

Is there a better approach to do this to reduce a click for the user?

Answer (score 1):

You need to place if else condition in `cellForRowAt` and need to check if file is already downloaded or not. Based on it you need to set `.checkmark` or `.detailDisclosureButton`.

One approach is to set boolean value in `TableData` to check if file is already downloaded. If you follow this approach no need to fetch selected cell in `accessoryButtonTappedForRowWith` you just need to change value of boolean flag on specific index of `TableData` and need reload single row.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)

    cell.textLabel?.text = TableData[indexPath.row]

    if (TableData[indexPath.row]).isDownloaded {
        cell.accessoryType = .checkmark   
    }else {
        cell.accessoryType = .detailDisclosureButton
    }


    return cell
}
```

Reload single row:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, accessoryButtonTappedForRowWith indexPath: IndexPath) {
    // doSomethingWithItem(indexPath.row)

    if let audioUrl = URL(string: "https://rss.example.com.mp3") {

        // then lets create your document folder url
        let documentsDirectoryURL =  FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!

        // lets create your destination file url
        let destinationUrl = documentsDirectoryURL.appendingPathComponent(audioUrl.lastPathComponent)
        print(destinationUrl)

        // to check if it exists before downloading it
        if FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: destinationUrl.path) {
            print("The file already exists at path")

            (TableData[indexPath]).isDownloaded = true
            tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: UITableViewRowAnimation.none)

            // if the file doesn't exist
        } else {

            // you can use NSURLSession.sharedSession to download the data asynchronously
            URLSession.shared.downloadTask(with: audioUrl, completionHandler: { (location, response, error) -> Void in
                guard let location = location, error == nil else { return }
                do {
                    // after downloading your file you need to move it to your destination url
                    try FileManager.default.moveItem(at: location, to: destinationUrl)
                    print("File moved to documents folder")
                } catch let error as NSError {
                    print(error.localizedDescription)
                }

            }).resume()

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

One approach would be to refactor the code out of `accessoryButtonTappedForRowWith` to another method, let's say `checkIfDownloaded(at:)` and call that method from `accessoryButtonTappedForRowWith` and from `cellForRowAt`:

```
// MARK: Utility methods
func audioURL(for indexPath: IndexPath) -> URL? {
    if let audioUrl = URL(string: "https://rss.example.com.mp3") {
        return audioUrl
    } else {
        return nil
    }
}

func fileLocation(for indexPath: IndexPath) -> URL? {
    if let audioUrl = audioURL(for: indexPath) {

        // then lets create your document folder url
        let documentsDirectoryURL =  FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!

        // lets create your destination file url
        let destinationUrl = documentsDirectoryURL.appendingPathComponent(audioUrl.lastPathComponent)
        return destinationUrl
    } else {
        return nil
    }
}

func checkIfDownloaded(at indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
    // doSomethingWithItem(indexPath.row)

    if let audioUrl = URL(string: "https://rss.example.com.mp3") {

        // then lets create your document folder url
        let documentsDirectoryURL =  FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!

        // lets create your destination file url
        let destinationUrl = documentsDirectoryURL.appendingPathComponent(audioUrl.lastPathComponent)
        print(destinationUrl)

        // to check if it exists before downloading it
        if FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: destinationUrl.path) {
            print("The file already exists at path")

            return false
        } else {
            return true
        }
    }
}

func downloadAudioIfNotDownloaded(for indexPath: IndexPath, completion: (( /* downloaded */ Bool) -> Void)?) -> URL? {
    if !checkIfDownloaded(at: indexPath),
        let audioURL = audioURL(for: indexPath),
        let destinationUrl = fileLocation(for: indexPath) {
        // you can use NSURLSession.sharedSession to download the data asynchronously
        URLSession.shared.downloadTask(with: audioURL, completionHandler: { (location, response, error) -> Void in
            guard let location = location, error == nil else {
                completion?(false)
                return }
            do {
                // after downloading your file you need to move it to your destination url
                try FileManager.default.moveItem(at: location, to: destinationUrl)
                print("File moved to documents folder")
                // success
                completion?(true)
            } catch let error as NSError {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
                completion?(false)
            }

        }).resume()
    } else {
        // was already downloaded
        completion?(true)
    }
}

// MARK: TableView delegate/datasource methods
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, accessoryButtonTappedForRowWith indexPath: IndexPath) {
    downloadAudioIfNotDownloaded(for: indexPath, completion: { success in
        // fix up a new accessory view/
    })
}


override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = ...

    if checkIfDownloaded(at: indexPath) {
        cell.accessoryType = .checkmark
    } else {
        cell.accessoryType = .detailDisclosureButton
        // although if you are starting to download automaticlly here
        // make sure the user won't start it by herself while one download already is happening
        downloadAudioIfNotDownloaded(for: indexPath, completion: { success in
            // fix up a new accessory view/
        })
    }
    return cell
}
```

Comment: This seems like a good solution. I am running into one error for the line `if checkIfDownloaded(at: indexPath) {` where it gives: `'()' is not convertible to 'Bool'`. Trying to fix now -- let me know if you have any ideas, and I can accept the answer.

Comment: @darkginger I have updated the code, it's a bit more complicated than I thought at the beginning, but maybe it will get you on the right track